# In Erlang, where are the builtin head and tail functions?

Tags: list, erlang

I know one can use pattern matching to extract the head and tail from a list. But is that *necessary*? There's nothing called `head` or `tail` in the `lists` module, and erl. (It does include `nth/2` and `nthtail/2`, which are more powerful, but those seem like unnaturally verbose ways to achieve `head` and `tail`.)

I'm not finding them in the top namespace either:

```
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

Eshell V12.0  (abort with ^G)
1> head([1,2]).
** exception error: undefined shell command head/1
2> tail([1,2]).
** exception error: undefined shell command tail/1
```

Comment: It seems like you could turn the question around and ask if head and tail are necessary since you can do this with pattern matching.

Comment: Even the Game of Life is Turing-complete; it's just difficult to read or write programs in. I think head and tail improve readability, as they let you reduce the number of variables to remember the definitions of. (Sure, it's not a hard definition, but every little bit of clarity helps.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern matching is the recommended way to access head and tail in lists. Code using functions to access them too often probably is not very good idiomatic Erlang. Nevertheless, in rare occasions the functions are indeed useful. You can find them among other Erlang Built In Functions at [this link](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html) under the names `hd` and `tl`.

Comment: Why the taboo? If a list is in scope and you'd like to take its head, calling `hd` allows you to avoid introducing a new variable. It makes for more readable code.

Comment: @JeffreyBenjaminBrown there is no "taboo". Lists are not arrays and the need to access a specific element of a list - like its head - is actually rare. Except for the case of recursive traversal through the list when folding is not enough. In this case we need the head and the tail, but pattern matching provides them more naturally and directly.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern Matching is a standard way in functional programming languages to operate over data, and Erlang is no exception. Hence exists a way to deal with Lists as well. And then again, `List` being a `native`/`built-in`/`primitive` type, available are those `hd` and `tl` BIF(s) to operate over them.